# Unclear Facebook Graph API deprecation warning

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, firebase-authentication, facebook-ios-sdk

My iOS app is using Firebase + Facebook (version 7.1.1) to authenticate users.

I have now received the following warning:

> Your App currently has access to Graph API v3.0 which will reach the
> end of its 2-year lifetime on 28 July, 2020. To ensure a smooth
> transition, please migrate all calls to Graph API v3.1 or higher. Use
> the API Upgrade Tool to understand exactly how this change will impact
> your app.

The API upgrade tool shows the following:

[image: Facebook API Upgrade Tool]

I am assuming (not sure) that the login is using this end-point, since the only usage of `GraphRequest` is the following:

- graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "picture.type(large)"]
- graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id"]
- graphPath: "me/friends", parameters: ["fields": "id"]

I am using a custom Facebook login button and therefore using the following to login:

```
let permissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]

LoginManager().logIn(permissions: permissions, from: viewController) { _, error in
    // implementation
}
```

What exactly do I need to change to avoid seeing this warning?

Comment: These warnings are issued automatically, based on the only thing Facebook sees - your API calls. That doesn’t mean with the change your app will break, and it doesn’t mean it won’t, either. If you don’t know what the change mentioned in the description means for your app, and whether it is relevant - then you best go check that with firebase.

Comment: The code that I mention above is using classes from the Facebook SDK. Not sure that firebase is the issue here.

Comment: I would not expect any problems with the core SDK functionality, as long as the SDK version you are using is up to date. But whether this change will otherwise affect your app, probably still mostly depends on the `// implementation` part.

Comment: I also got a similar message from Facebook and since 28-July my service calls are failing with rate limit exceeded error(403).

Comment: @José did you manage to solve this?

Comment: Not sure if I remember, but you can change in the Facebook developer console (settings/advanced) what Graph API version you want to use. I changed mine to 7.1.1 and have not received this warning anymore.